# Transforming data from wide to long where 'lengths(varying)' > 'length(times)'

Tags: r, pivot, reshape, tidyr, reshape2

I am trying to convert data from df to df2.

```
> df
  part.id bl.rbc bl.serum bl.hp bl.epfa sm.rbc sm.serum sm.hp sm.epfa oy.rbc oy.serum oy.hp
1       1     NA       NA    NA      NA     NA       NA    NA      NA     NA       NA    NA
2       2     NA       NA    NA      NA     NA       NA    NA      NA     NA       NA    NA
3       3     NA       NA    NA      NA     NA       NA    NA      NA     NA       NA    NA
  oy.epfa
1      NA
2      NA
3      NA


> df2
  part.id timepoint rbc serum hp epfa
1       1        bl  NA    NA NA   NA
2       2        sm  NA    NA NA   NA
3       3        oy  NA    NA NA   NA
```

I tried reshape but I get an error if lengths(varying) = 4 > length(time) = 3. My actual case involves 16 varying.

Code to create these:

```
part.id <- c(1,2,3)
bl.rbc <- NA
bl.serum <- NA
bl.hp <- NA
bl.epfa <- NA
sm.rbc <- NA
sm.serum <- NA
sm.hp <- NA
sm.epfa <- NA
oy.rbc <- NA
oy.serum <- NA
oy.hp <- NA
oy.epfa <- NA


df <- data.frame(part.id, 
                 bl.rbc, bl.serum, bl.hp, bl.epfa, 
                 sm.rbc, sm.serum, sm.hp, sm.epfa,
                 oy.rbc, oy.serum, oy.hp, oy.epfa)

timepoint <- c("bl", "sm", "oy")

rbc <- NA
serum <- NA
hp <- NA
epfa <- NA

df2 <- data.frame(part.id, timepoint, rbc, serum, hp, epfa)
```

Comment: Not clear about the expected output

Comment: How about now? I included all names.

Comment: please provide data. we can't base our coding experience on variable names alone.

Comment: Done - thanks for requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't match your expected output, but perhaps what you intended?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  rename_at(-1, ~ str_replace(., "(\\w+).(\\w+)", "\\2_\\1")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-part.id, names_to = c(".value", "timepoint"), names_sep='_')

# A tibble: 9 x 6
  part.id timepoint rbc   serum hp    epfa 
    <dbl> <chr>     <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1       1 bl        NA    NA    NA    NA   
2       1 sm        NA    NA    NA    NA   
3       1 oy        NA    NA    NA    NA   
4       2 bl        NA    NA    NA    NA   
5       2 sm        NA    NA    NA    NA   
6       2 oy        NA    NA    NA    NA   
7       3 bl        NA    NA    NA    NA   
8       3 sm        NA    NA    NA    NA   
9       3 oy        NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had trouble with pivot_longer because I did not know I needed to have underscores in my names. 

May you explain what `rename_at(-1, ~` is doing?

Comment: The `-1` since you don't want to apply `rename_at` for the first column (`part.id`)...and tilde `~` is shorthand for `funs()` to provide relevant function for input to `rename_at`...